# Shipping step on checkout not visible

Tags: magento2, checkout

For some reason the first checkout step "Shipping" is not visible.
I checked all settings, but was not able to find the solution.
Thanks for any hint.

Comment: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/3902

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the weight of the product that you added to the cart on the admin edit page. If the current weight is less than 0 or equal to 0, you should change it to a positive value. for ex. 0.99